# Get a photo of the entire page with HTML

Tags: python, html, screenshot, photo, vk

**I need to get a "screenshot" of the page by having the HTML of the page.**
There is a list of links to VK pages, you need to get photos of correspondence from each link as quickly and efficiently as possible.

I tried using selenium to solve the problem, and I quite liked the result, only the speed is a huge problem. After all, I have to take screenshots of hundreds of conversations.

Comment: Start by providing your current code as a [mre] and clearly explain what is the bottleneck